# Select Users with top score on given DATE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple sql table (SCORES), only one table, no JOIN:

```
userid    score   date
|1       1     2017-09-31
|1       1     2017-10-01
|2       2     2017-10-01
|1       2     2017-10-02
|2       2     2017-10-02
|3       1     2017-10-02
```

I want to select userid on a given day with top score, so

On 2017-09-31 , it should return userid 1

On 2017-10-01 , it should return userid 2 ( since higher score)

On 2017-10-02, it will return both user id 1 and 2 ( since both scores are 2)

I tried this mysql but not working correctly :

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(score) AS hiscore, date
FROM scores 
WHERE date =:date
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY hiscore DESC
```

and I am getting this :

On 2017-09-31 returns userid 1 (correct)

On 2017-10-01 . return userid 1 and userid 2 and the top scores they had that day , which is not what I want

any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I think your problem might be related to the group by clause, it returns the MAX value for each group, hence why for 2017-10-01 it also returns the 1 for userid 1. What you want specifically might require some slightly more advanced sql

Comment: This query did the job for me `SELECT user_id, score AS hiscore, date
FROM scores 
WHERE date = :date
AND score IN (
    SELECT MAX(score)
    FROM scores 
    WHERE date = :date
)
ORDER BY user_id DESC`

Comment: thanks that worked

Comment: @knb Nothing changes if you add a max date, the problem in the query is that `max` returns a max value per group (when you `group by`). Since he is grouping by user_id he gets 2/3 groups each with its own `max` score. [This](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-max-function/) is how `MAX` and `GROUP BY` work together, you have to scroll a bit down to **MySQL MAX with GROUP BY clause**.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Group_concat(user_id separator ','), score AS hiscore, date
FROM scores 
WHERE date =:date
and (score) in
                  (select max(score) from scores group by date)
;
```

Comment: not returning anything

Comment: what are you providing as `date` ?

Comment: string "2017-09-31" as an example

Comment: what is the datatype of `date`?

Comment: its only a String

Comment: Please run this query and paste the output here :`select date,max(score) from scores group by date;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157901/discussion-between-harshil-and-user3150060).

Comment: Have you tried the query mentioned in comment?